# deploy h2o.ai trained learner in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, h2o.ai

I am reading article titles that suggest h2o.ai integrates its ML in/with snowflake.
https://www.h2o.ai/resources/solution-brief/integration-of-h2o-driverless-ai-with-snowflake/

If I wanted to export a POJO learner like a gbm and have it run in snowflake, is there a clean way to do that?  I didn't see any clear directions in the (several) articles I found.

How does that integrate with ML-ops?

Answer (score 1):

One way to integrate models built in H2o.ai is to integrate through [Snowflake External Function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions.html)s.

This is documented at https://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/snowflake-integration.html

H2o.ai also have (or will have shortly) support to deploy models into [Snowflake Java UDFs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/java/udf-java.html) and it is described in  https://www.h2o.ai/blog/h2o-integrates-with-snowflake-snowpark-java-udfs-how-to-better-leverage-the-snowflake-data-marketplace-and-deploy-in-database/